# Reflection + libraries java

Tags: java, reflection

Edit: this is the Project Setup:

IDE: Eclipse:

Project1 : "Server"

```
src:
com/mainpackage/main.java
libs:
commons-x-0.jar
PluginInterface.jar
```

all jar in libs-folder are on the buildpath.

Project2 : "PluginInterface"

```
src:
com/interfaces/plugininterface
```

Project3 : "Plugin"

```
src:
com/package/class1.java - (this implements plugininterface)
libs:
library1.jar
PluginInterface.jar
```

all jar in libs-folder are on the buildpath

so when i export the Plugin (Project3) i get a jar like this (excluded PluginInterface.jar from export)

```
com/
com/package/
com/package/class1.class
com/package/class1.java
libs/
libs/library1.jar
```

library1.jar looks as follows - it is not written by me:

```
com/
com/stuff/
com/stuff/libclass.java
com/stuff/libclass.class
```

now i Want to utilize class1 in the "Server" over the Interface:

```
ClassLoader loader=URLClassLoader.newInstance( 
                new URL[]{new URL("file:path/to/plugin.jar")},
                ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()
        );

Class<?> pluginclass = Class.forName("com.package.class1", true, loader);
plugininterface ref = (plugininterface)pluginclass.newInstance();
```

i can now call methods from class1 using the interface both projects know, because both of them include "PluginInterface.jar" in their buildpath.

THE PROBLEM:

"Server" does not recognize "libclass", because is neither in its path nor did i load the class from the plugin.jar in which the library1 is nested.

how do i access this class if an import as library is not possible at the server?

Thanks for any help!

Edit: just for the sake if someone ever has this Problem again, i'll add the ANT files' build-target that makes it work:

```
<target name="build">
     <javac destdir="bin" includeantruntime="false" source="1.7" target="1.7">
        <src path="src"/>
        <classpath refid="Plugin.classpath"/>
     </javac>
    <unzip src="${libs}/library1.jar" dest="bin/">
        <patternset>
            <include name="**/*.class"/>
        </patternset>
</unzip>
    <jar destfile="plugin.jar" basedir="bin"></jar> 
</target>
```

Just copy the contents of the Library-jar into the build directory (in my case ./bin/). it then isn't even necessary to feed the libraryclasses to the Classloader, it finds them when loading the Classes use them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The standard class loader does not support nested jar files. You could programmatically extract the jar, or write your own classloader which will decompress the nested files on demand. However, you'd be swimming against the current: such packaging is just not recommended. Instead it is recommended to explode the nested jar into its parent. This is, for example, what Maven dependency plugin does, and the default way to publish a Clojure application with Leiningen.

To achieve your goal from Eclipse the best approach seems be this:

1. have Eclipse's Export JAR wizard save the ant build scripts it internally generates to build your JAR;
2. adapt the resulting script to meet your specific needs;
3. in the future don't run the wizard anymore, but the ant script.

Comment: (This is because `ZipFile` does not support nested zips. You can read through zip files with `ZipInputStream` from any source.)

Comment: In Java 7 you could probably write a custom filesystem which "deep plunges" into embedded zip files... But even then, conflicts could arise

Comment: so how would I then load Plugins that use libraries that my server does not know (eg)?

Comment: @billdoor Add the jar as an External JAR file, a library. Are you using Eclipse or command line or what to compile this?

Comment: @ Alex, the sense behind this is, i want to add and remove plugins from the application without rebuilding it all the time. so adding as a library does not meet my requirements :/

Comment: @billdoor Your requirement doesn't motivate nested JARs.

Comment: @Marko
so how would I then load Plugins that use libraries that my server does not know (eg)?

Comment: Your question is utterly vague. What server, what plugins, what does it mean that a server "knows" about it, ...

Comment: ok sorry, i try to rephrase: the plugin-project has a library in its buildpath, which provides "testclass". how can a project use "testclass" by importing the first plugin-project.jar file in my question? or: how can i provide the classes in the nested jar, without a nested jar?

Comment: If you're talking about Eclipse plugins, OSGi supports installing bundles at runtime

Comment: i will try to rephrase the questtion - its a plugin for a server that i wrote (had to write) myself, and currently i have to include all libraries added in plugins also at the server

Comment: Did you try to just explode the nested jar into the outer? That would be the standard practice in cases such as yours.

Comment: how would i do this when exportin from eclipse?

Comment: You'll just need to write your own build code. Eclipse itself also uses ant for this internally, generating a build script on the fly. I believe you can have it save the file, so start with that and edit it further to meet your specific need.

Comment: There, I've pasted the comments into the answer and adapted.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Marko, your standard class loader will not scan through nested jars and nested jars within them. However, if you're willing to play around with [TrueZip](https://truezip.java.net/), you can easily do this without having to extract archives or anything. What's better is that you can have nested archives within nested archives as deep as as you like. So your path could look like:

```
/path/to/foo.jar/bar/foo/my.zip/containing/some.tar/com/foo/My.class
```

If you feel comfortable writing your own classloader using TrueZip, this would be a neat way to do it. If not, then you'd have to write a utility class that parses the path and extracts the archives first, before feeding it into the standard `URLClassloader`.